# Mailcore2 library file size almost 200MB Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

I am using mailcore2 for a while now, but I am running into the problem that the library file size is way too big at the extend that can't even commit my code to Github. Does somebody know a workarround or a way to reeduce this library in size?

I installed mailcore2 through my podfile with "use_frameworks!", and I went through all the steps of the bridging header file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailcore2 is distributed as a 192MB archive file, there's not much you can do about that.

Apparently you're currently versioning your local `Pods` directory along with your source code, which is not strictly required - you can add it to your `.gitignore` file and remove it from your git index if it's bothering you. See http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control for pros and cons of not versioning your Pods.